# If Allah doesn't need our worship rather we need to worship Him, why did He create us with the purpose of worshipping Him in the first place?

Tags: allah, life, mankind

> “O mankind! It is you who stand in need of Allah, but Allah is Rich [Free of all wants and needs], Worthy of all praise” - [Surah Fatir 35:15](https://quran.com/35/15/)

> “And I (Allah) created not the jinn and mankind except that they should worship Me (Alone)” - [Surah al-Dhaariyaat 51:56](https://quran.com/51/56/)

If Allah doesn't need us, rather we need to worship Him, then doesn't that invalidate (or at least weaken/nullify to an extent) the purpose of human beings to begin with? What kind of paradoxical and confusing cycle is that?

Or are there purposes other than worshipping Him that I am unaware of? Is the test of life and passing it the purpose? If so, then it is quite purposeless because once we pass it we go to heaven and chill there for eternity (or fail and burn in hell). That's all? How and why can that be considered a purpose? Is that all we are meant to do?

These thoughts have been bothering me lately. Help a brother out if you have the knowledge. Jazakallah.

Comment: I don't understand how it 'invalidates or weakens' the purpose. That is our purpose in life: to worship Allah and do good. Why Allah created us is irrelevant, and we don't need to know.

Comment: This question should certainly have an answer see [If god is a perfect being why does he desire to be glorified](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46016/if-god-is-a-perfect-being-why-does-he-desire-to-be-glorified), [If Allah created mankind only to worship him why did he give them freewill=](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45657/if-allah-created-mankind-only-to-worship-him-why-did-he-give-them-freewill) and [Why should we worship God when he doesn't need our worship?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/458/why-we-should-worship-god-when-he-doesnt-need-our-worship)

Answer (score 1):

Our purpose is not weakened because Allah does not need us. It is still our purpose to worship Allah and do good. What Allah needs is not relevant.

As to your question about why Allah created us with that purpose: Allah knows best. You don't really need to and it is probably impossible to know Allah's reasons.

Answer (score -1):

> Verse (51:56) And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to
>   worship Me.

We all know the creation and test of ADAM and the result, that was all for us to show.

Now we are in the same test (by above verse it is clear).

> Verse (2:26) Indeed, Allah is not timid to present an example - that of a mosquito or what is smaller than it. And those who have believed know that it is the truth from their Lord. But as for those who disbelieve, they say, "What did Allah intend by this as an example?" He misleads many thereby and guides many thereby. And He misleads not except the defiantly disobedient,

Peace of heart:

> Verse (13:28) Those who have believed and whose hearts are assured by
>   the remembrance of Allah. Only in remembrance of Allah will your heart find peace

By worshiping Allah we are not going to add anything to his highness or by not worshiping we can harm him, It's we, who need his help in every single step of this life and here after.